# helm3 - upgrade does not refresh pod with force

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

We are deploying Java microservices to AWS 'ECR > EKS' using helm3 and Jenkins CI/CD pipeline. However what we see is, if we re-run Jenkins job to re-install the deployment/pod, then the pod does not re-install if there are no code changes. It still keeps the old running pod as is. **Use case considered here is,** *AWS Secrets Manager configuration for db secret pulled during deployment has changed, so service needs to be redeployed by re-triggering the Jenkins job.*

### **Approach 1** :   https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/

I tried using 'helm upgrade --install --force ....' as suggested in helm3 upgrade documentation but it fails with below error in Jenkins log

> "Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to replace object: Service "dbservice" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable"

### **Approach 2** : using --recreate-pods from earlier helm version

With 'helm upgrade --install --recreate-pods ....', I  am getting below warning in Jenkins log

> "Flag --recreate-pods has been deprecated, functionality will no longer be updated. Consult the documentation for other methods to recreate pods"

However, the pod gets recreated. But as we know --recreate-pods is not soft-restart. Thus we would have downtime, which breaks the microservice principle.

#### helm version used

*version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.4.0", GitCommit:"7090a89efc8a18f3d8178bf47d2462450349a004", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.14.10"}*

#### question

- How to use --force with helm 3 with helm upgrade for above error ?
- How to achieve soft-restart with deprecated --recreate-pods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is how I configured it - Thanks to @vasili-angapov for redirecting to correct documentation section.

In `deployment.yaml`, I added annotations and rollme

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 5 | quote }}
```

As per documentation, each invocation of the template function `randAlphaNum` will generate a unique random string. Thus random string always changes and causes the deployment to roll.

The other way described in the document is with respect to a changing SHA value for a file.

*In the past helm recommended using the --recreate-pods flag as another option. This flag has been marked as `deprecated in Helm 3` in favor of the more declarative method above.*

Comment: This is the correct (and a good) answer, but --recreate-pods was cleaner for local testing. In my case I have a local k8s cluster for dev purposes and an accompany AKS instance for the cloud. Locally I want to roll the deployments as the image label is always "latest", in the cloud I don't need to do this as the image has a tag so will re-deploy on an update. I can make this answer work by using some conditional logic in my helm chart to apply the randAlphaNum value to that annotation on local installs only, but I think this is clunky compared to the old method. RIP --recreate-pods

Answer (score 5):

This is nicely described in Helm documentation: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Comment: looks like this is what I am after. I will check it again if it works.